# Handling array parsed from a Query string and perfoming a http_build_query()

Tags: php, http

I need to take an array like I have below:

```
$Ayellow = $_GET['3456Bold'];
$Featry = $_GET['234'];
$Timestamp = $now->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$UserID = $_GET['MyID'];
$Version = $_GET['1.0'];
$Login = $_GET['Password'];
    
$parameters = array($Ayellow,$Featry,$Timestamp,$UserID,$Version);
// Sort parameters by name.
    ksort($parameters);

// URL encode the parameters.
$encoded = array();
foreach ($parameters as $name => $value) {
    $encoded[] = rawurlencode($name) . '=' . rawurlencode($value);
}

// Concatenate the sorted and URL encoded parameters into a string.
$concatenated = implode('&', $encoded);

// Compute signature and add it to the parameters.
$parameters['Signature'] =
   rawurlencode(hash_hmac('sha256', $concatenated, $Login, false));

// Replace with the URL of your API host.
$url = "https://someexamplesite.com";

// Build Query String
$queryString = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

// print out queryprint
// echo ($parameters);
echo ($url."?".$queryString);
```

My result doing this in php is:

https://someexamplesite.com?**0**=3456Bold&**1**=234&**2**=2020-08-09T15%3A04%3A46%2B0000&**3**=MyID&**4**=1.0&**Signature**=gy2bhggbghjjjhhjggv....... (64bit random string)

Expected result is:

https://someexamplesite.com?**Ayellow**=3456Bold&**Featry**=234&**Timestamp**=2020-08-09T15%3A04%3A46%2B0000&**UserID**=MyID&**Version**=1.0&**Signature**=gy2bhggbghjjjhhjggv....... (64bit random string)

Simply put how do I get the names of the array rather than the index number inputed in the query string . (I sincerely hope I am clear on my request).

I need help to figure this out, my search has yielded nothing due to my low experience and lerning
curve.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give your `$parameters` - Array the wanted keys.

For example like:
`'Ayellow' => $Ayellow`

Otherwise the keys in the Array are just counting up (like it should).

```php
$Ayellow = $_GET['3456Bold'];
$Featry = $_GET['234'];
$Timestamp = $now->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$UserID = $_GET['MyID'];
$Version = $_GET['1.0'];
$Login = $_GET['Password'];
    
$parameters = array('Ayellow' => $Ayellow, 'Featry' => $Featry, 'Timestamp' => $Timestamp, 'UserID' => $UserID, 'Version' => $Version);
// Sort parameters by name.
    ksort($parameters);

// URL encode the parameters.
$encoded = array();
foreach ($parameters as $name => $value) {
    $encoded[] = rawurlencode($name) . '=' . rawurlencode($value);
}

// Concatenate the sorted and URL encoded parameters into a string.
$concatenated = implode('&', $encoded);

// Compute signature and add it to the parameters.
$parameters['Signature'] =
   rawurlencode(hash_hmac('sha256', $concatenated, $Login, false));

// Replace with the URL of your API host.
$url = "https://someexamplesite.com";

// Build Query String
$queryString = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

// print out queryprint
// echo ($parameters);
echo ($url."?".$queryString);
```

Comment: Goosh. so quick and so very correct. Thank you i am so grateful

Comment: Associative Array

An associative array is a list of values that are accessed via a key instead of index numbers. The key can be any value but it must be unique to the array.
~~~
<?php
$student_scores = array("Joe" => 83, "Frank" => "93", "Benji" => "90");
?>
~~~
$student_scores['Joe'] would return 83, $student_scores['Frank'] would return 93, $student_scores['Benji'] would return 90.